# Discovering Apache configuration without access to http.conf

Tags: apache-2.2

For my webpage at my university I can place files in a directory that can be served by apache. Also at least php is supported.

What I am wondering is, what apache modules are available? E.g. I want to know or I can use wsgi or mod_python.

How can I discover or this modules are enabled? I have access to: all files in my directory (including .htaccess) and the access + error logs. I don't have access to the webserver itself. Is there some easy way I can display all modules in use or other config variables?

Comment: Do you have SSH access, FTP, or ??

Comment: @Khaled I have access to the files through a shared disk (NFS)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would run phpinfo() in a php file to discover what Apache modules are loaded. Create a file with the following line of code:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Executing on the server gives tons of information about PHP but also some about Apache:

[image: Apache2handler]

You can see what modules are loaded in Apache and some other information. You don't get the full configuration file (as that would also be a security problem) but you can get which modules are loaded.

Comment: Never would have thought of it, but it was so simple.

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways you can check this

- Check the apache header (look for the Server Signature) and see which modules are declared (keep in mind not always modules declare themselves)
- Just try directly to execute code and see what works and what not, not the best way but 100% success rate ;)